# Let $f$ be a mapping, $\beta$ be an ordinal, $X=\{\alpha\mid f(\alpha)\le \beta\}$, and $\gamma=\sup X$. Is $\gamma\in X$?

Tags: functions, supremum-and-infimum, ordinals

> Let $f:\operatorname{Ord}\to\operatorname{Ord}$ be a mapping consisting of only addition, multiplication, and exponentiation operations, and $\beta$ be an ordinal. Let $X=\{\alpha\mid f(\alpha)\le \beta\}$ and $\gamma=\sup X$.

1. I would like to ask if $\gamma\in X$ or not?
2. Is there certain conditions on $f$ to make sure that $\gamma\in X$?

When I deal with simple mapping such as $f(\alpha)=\delta\cdot\alpha$, I found that $\gamma\in X$. I don't know if we can generalize it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Consider $f(\alpha)=\alpha+\alpha=\alpha\cdot2$ and $\beta=\omega$.

Comment: Or $f(\alpha)=\alpha+1$ and $\beta=\omega$.

Comment: You are asking about continuity. The operations $\alpha+\beta$, $\alpha\cdot\beta$, $\alpha^\beta$ are continuous in $\beta$ but not in $\alpha$.

Comment: Have you studied topology? Do you know about the order topology on a linearly ordered set?

Comment: Thank you @bof! I've just been exposed to basic set theory and ordinal arithmetic up to this point. I have not learned anything about topology. I'm unable to get why you give me $f(\alpha)=\alpha\cdot2$ and $f(\alpha)=\alpha+1$. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Did you mean $f(\alpha)=\alpha\cdot2$ and $f(\alpha)=\alpha+1$ are not continuous?

Comment: Please check my reasoning! 1. $f(\alpha)=\alpha\cdot2$ and $\beta=\omega$. Then $X=\omega$ and $\sup X=\omega\notin\omega$. 2. $f(\alpha)=\alpha+1$ and $\beta=\omega$. Then $X=\omega$ and $\sup X=\omega\notin\omega$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Thank you @bof !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property you are asking for is continuity. More succinctly written, continuity for $\operatorname{Ord}\to\operatorname{Ord}$ functions is when

$$f(\gamma)=\sup_{\alpha\in\gamma}f(\alpha)=\sup\{f(\alpha)~|~\alpha\in\gamma\}$$

for every limit ordinal $\gamma$. It is notable that the functions you are talking about are increasing functions, so if $\gamma\in X$, then $f(\gamma)\ge f(\delta)$ for every $\gamma>\delta$. Ordinal functions which are strictly increasing and continuous are called [normal functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_function).

Determining when your expressions are normal is not so hard, as it is the case that $\alpha+\beta,\alpha\cdot\beta,$ and $\alpha^\beta$ are all normal in $\beta$, but they are not normal in $\alpha$.